# Discontinuity of the geometric phase

Tags: many-body, topological-phase, berry-pancharatnam-phase

Does the geometric phase accumulated along a closed trajectory (in some parameter space) has to be continuous?

Answer (score 3):

The geometric phase can experience discontinuous dependence on the parameter space in the vicinity of diabolical points (i.e., points where the Hamiltonian eigenvalues are degenerate but the eigenvectors are distinct) and exceptional points where both eigenvalues and eigenvectors are degenerate. Exceptional points appear in non-Hermitian Hamiltonians used to model open quantum systems.

Please see the following [article](http://arxiv.org/abs/0806.3720v1)  by: Nesterov and de la Cruz for a detailed exposition.

The Berry curvature has a monopole singularity at the diabolical points. Diabolical points corresponding to higher classes of degeneracies can give rise to higher Chern numbers, please see the following  [article](http://nanowiki.phy.bme.hu/images/5/5b/Amjp_Garg.pdf) by: Garg.

This subject is still under very active research, please see for example the following [work](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/David_Viennot/publication/228338365_The_need_for_a_flat_higher_gauge_structure_to_describe_a_Berry_phase_associated_with_some_resonance_phenomena/links/00b49539ff5df1a763000000.pdf)  by Viennot